# Can I visualize the output values of my linear regression model, If I have got 3 predictor variables and 1 target variable?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to understand whether I can Visualize a 4-dimensional graph by breaking it down into smaller dimensions.
For example when we have a 2-d plane as a prediction for a 3-d graph, We can just chose a 2-d graph that shows our prediction as a line. Can I do the same for a 4-d graph? If yes then how?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

data = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
data = data[:50] #taking just 50 rows from the excel file

model = linear_model.LinearRegression() #loading the model from the library
model.fit(data[['median_income','total_rooms','households']],data.median_house_value)

# Pls add code here for visualizations
```

Comment: Not really, at least I can't visualize 4-dimensional objects. One option is to visualize a few dimensions at a time, or doing a [principal component analysis / linear discriminant analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html) and hope the lower-dimensional space is representative of the higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can do one funny thing - since your object is a function from R^3->R, you could, in principle, take your input space as a 3d cube (I am guessing your data is somewhat bounded), and then use *colour* to code your prediction. This way you will get a 3d coloured point cloud. You will probably need transparency to see through it + some interactive investigation to rotate/move around, but 4d is the highest "visualisable" dimension (as long as one dimension is "special" and thus can be coded as a colour).